# How to run Hot Chocolate Graphql in .net core over HTTPS

Tags: asp.net-core, graphql

Ive been trying to find a way to serve the request for Hot Chocolate  v11 Graphql over https. And since from what i read is that serves over http request.

Why over https ?
Because the application is hosted over kubernetes and needs to run as https.

Any suggestion or pointing to some information since i havent been able to find any information on google.

Answer (score 0):

Hot Chocolate is an asp.net core app so you secure it over https just like you would any asp.net core app.

https://chillicream.com/docs/hotchocolate/security

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/enforcing-ssl?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: ive managed to run .net core app over https. However when first loading the request gets routed fine. However after initial request, https request for Graphql pipeline doesnt get routed correctly and it returns 404 in console logging. Also it isnt able to fetch schema even though app runs fine